# WCF sql dataset Over 50 records will not save

Tags: vb.net, wcf, timeout

Have spent over 20 hrs searching the web and still cant get basichttpbinding to save when 
has a number of records (okay when a small number of records)

The service Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel" />
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"  maxRequestLength="102400"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>



    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="IncidentServiceBehavior" name="NewIncidentService_IService">
        <endpoint address="" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
          contract="IncidentServiceReference.ServiceClient" />
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Incident"
          name="" contract="IncidentServiceReference.ServiceClient" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="01:10:00" />
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>


    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="01:10:00"
          openTimeout="01:10:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="524288" maxStringContentLength="524288"
            maxArrayLength="524288" maxBytesPerRead="524288" maxNameTableCharCount="524288" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Incident" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"
          useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="524288" maxStringContentLength="524288"
            maxArrayLength="524288" maxBytesPerRead="524288" maxNameTableCharCount="524288" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

    </bindings>



    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="IncidentServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="524288" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The client App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
    </startup>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"/>
  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>



              <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                       maxReceivedMessageSize="524288"
                       maxBufferSize="524288"
                       maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                       receiveTimeout="01:10:00"
                       transferMode="Streamed"
                       sendTimeout="01:10:00"
                       closeTimeout="01:10:00"
                       hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                       openTimeout="01:10:00"
                       messageEncoding="Text"
                       textEncoding="utf-8"
                       allowCookies="false"
                       bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                       useDefaultWebProxy="false">
                <security mode="None">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                             proxyCredentialType="None"
                             realm="" />
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                           algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
              </binding>



            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="IncidentServiceBehavior">
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="524288"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>



      <client>
            <endpoint address="---Removed for security-----"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                contract="IncidentServiceReference.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" behaviorConfiguration="IncidentServiceBehavior" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>


Has a 413 error - changed to streamed, now get a 400.  Error from WCF Test Client

The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService.saveTasks(saveTasksRequest request)
   at ServiceClient.IService.saveTasks(saveTasksRequest request)

Inner Exception:
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

Yes it appears to be a time out,  any changes not affect.  Have added a timeout in the connectionstring  and in IIS 7.0 have added 'serverruntime uploadreadaheadsize="20480000" '

any thoughts would be appreciated

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

May have a solution for this.

Found this

binding name="" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">

at this site

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/481526/Theplusremoteplusserverplusreturnedplusanplusunexp

Needs to before any other basichttpbinding and note that there is no name.  I think this set the default values.  have set up a test to see if it work and has not failed yet.  I will (when time permits) change the values from 2gigs to lower values.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.

Andrew